# Is there such thing as a measure theoretic limit?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

In real functions, do we have a notion of one-sided measure theoretic limits? I want to define them with the following:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c^+} f(x) = L$

iff

$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta > 0, J:=f((c,c+\delta)), \mu( J \cap B_\epsilon(L)) = \mu(J )$

Comment: It sounds like the notion of an [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) continuous function is what you're looking for.

Comment: What about just a one-sided limit? Is there a notion of that? I couldn't find it in my searches.

Comment: I don't know, but can I suggest you rewrite your definition to use $f( (c, c+\delta) )$? Me, i needed to unwrap your set builder notation to get the idea of what you were talking about, while thinking about "the image of this interval" is very direct (to me).

Comment: Sure! I like that idea. I just changed it and I think it looks nicer this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it should be noted that the image of a Borel set by a continuous function may not be Borel, so there might be measurability issues.

Let $n$ be an integer, $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ be subsets that partition $\mathbb{R}$, and $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ real numbers. Consider $f := \sum^n_{i=1} \alpha_i \textbf{1}_{A_i}$.

Then $f$ verifies your condition everywhere, since $\mu(\{f(x) \ \vert \ x \in \mathbb{R}\}) = 0$.

In fact, if you want to define something, I think you should first make a list of whatever your definition is supposed to imply. For example, should your definition of measure-continuity-on-the-left be verified for continuous functions in the usual sense?

Comment: Great point about measurability issues. Also, I like your example function a lot. That's very useful.

Comment: Can we say something about the inverse image of a codomain ball needing to match the domain ball in all but a zero measure set?

Comment: Maybe defined like $\exists B_{\epsilon} , \mu(B_{\delta} \setminus f^{-1}(B_\epsilon)) = 0$